# More than one conditions in Where clause of Fusion Table Layer ignored in Styles

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I am writing with reference to an earlier question of mine, which also had to do with the use of Where clauses for Fusion Table Layer in Google Maps. [Link to earlier question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33664713/where-clauses-being-ignored-in-fusion-table-layer-in-google-maps) I have noticed that if the Where clause in Styles section has more than one filtering conditions in it, it is ignored altogether. Google Map/Fusion Tables Layers then ends up applying that Style to ALL of the features contained in that Fusion table. You can remove a filtering condition from the Where clause to make it a single filter where clause, and it then works as expected so I am pretty sure that it doesn't like multiple filtering condition in the SAME where clause (or the way I am writing it).

Here is an example that illustrates this behavior:

```
    layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  map: map,
  options: {
    templateId: 2
  },
  heatmap: { enabled: false },
  query: {
    select: "geometry",
     from: "1D6d93-0iT2zUCw8IvkbpDPYDx2-jA0ZAWXi07mQD",
  },      
        styles: [{

          //note multiple filters in the same Where clause.

          where: "((SHIFT_ID != 1) AND (SHIFT_ID != 2))",

          //you'd expect the following Style option applied to only those map features
          //which met above criteria. However, they are applied to ALL map features.

          polylineOptions: {
            strokeOpacity: 0.70,
            strokeColor: "#FFFFFF",
            strokeWeight: "5"  }

     //if Where clause is reduced to just having one filter, it works fine.
     //For example, either of the following two work fine by themselves.
     //where: "SHIFT_ID != 1"   --OR--
     //where: "SHIFT_ID != 2"    etc.

        }] 
});
```

Comment: When the query is invalid, the default behavior seems to be display everything (rather than do nothing...)

Comment: [where: "((SHIFT_ID != 1) AND (SHIFT_ID != 2))" works in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/2hx6t25c/4/) (or are you saying these results are not correct?)

Comment: For the life of me, I can't figure out what is invalid about the query. I have tried taking brackets out, putting them back in, replacing AND with "&" and "&&", interchanging single and double quotes, etc etc. Does anything jump at you from this query as what might be invalid. Field names match the case of how they are defined in the table. The field values are integers so no quotes around them (beside, they work fine as is when used in a single filter Where), etc.

Comment: @geocodezip: That's what I thought too that where: "((SHIFT_ID != 1) AND (SHIFT_ID != 2))" worked in the fiddle referenced to in your comment. It was only when I switched the order of individual sections in Styles block (I moved this Where section with multiple filters to be the last one as opposed to being first in Styles) that I noticed something was amiss. It only "appears" to work because it is drawn first. Then other Styles sections get drawn on top of it. Plus the fiddle as is shows entire map in White. That is wrong and also shows it didn't work. Only some should have been in White.

Answer (score 0):

Geocodezip was right; query was invalid.

This is what I have been able to determine re use of queries for Fusion Tables.

1. Can have multiple fields/filters in one where clause.
2. Can't use brackets "()" for Boolean logic.
3. Instead of !=, use NOT EQUAL TO
4. For NULL values, check equality with '' (empty string).
5. Field names are case sensitive.

https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/sql-reference

Comment: The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/sql-reference#Select) clearly states that `!=` should work with both numbers and strings, but it clearly doesn't.  It doesn't say anything about parentheses, so that was certainly part of the problem.  [Fiddle using NOT EQUAL TO](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/2hx6t25c/10/) (with infowindow indicating SHIFT_ID)