# Google Maps Fusion Layer ignores WHERE clause

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I am having an issue making the where clause within my fusion table layer actually do anything.

What below should do is select all rows from my fusion table where 'income' is above 100 (or for a specific geom (MSOA) if you swap the code out in the where clause).

The fusion table column average_income is type Number, MSOA11CD is type Text.

There is an old question here which is on the same topic but was solved via a syntax error that I do not have.
["WHERE" clauses being ignored in Fusion Table Layer in Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33664713/where-clauses-being-ignored-in-fusion-table-layer-in-google-maps)

Fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/dqthnw7s/

```
layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    map: map,
    heatmap: {
        enabled: false
    },
    query: {
        select: "*",
        from: "1QEMdQUSmsdEZs9vAchHeKPG_CsKa7L0zW0SBJSCu",
        where: "average_income > 100",
        //tried this too
        //where: 'MSOA11CD = \'E02004590\''

    },
    styles: [{
       where: "average_income > 1000",
        polygonOptions: {
            fillColor: '#002951'
        }
    }, {
        where: "average_income > 800 AND average_income <= 1000",
        polygonOptions: {
            fillColor: '#003466'
        }
    }, {
        where: 'average_income > 100 AND average_income <= 800',
        polygonOptions: {
            fillColor: '#376798'
        }
    }]
});
```

Fusion Table:
https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1QEMdQUSmsdEZs9vAchHeKPG_CsKa7L0zW0SBJSCu#rows:id=1

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

select "*" is not valid.  That needs to be a "geometry" column.

```
layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    map: map,
    heatmap: {
        enabled: false
    },
    query: {
        select: "geometry",
        from: "1QEMdQUSmsdEZs9vAchHeKPG_CsKa7L0zW0SBJSCu",
        where: "average_income > 100",
        //tried this too
        //where: 'MSOA_CODE = \'E02004590\''

    },
    styles: [{
       where: "average_income > 1000",
        polygonOptions: {
            fillColor: '#002951'
        }
    }, {
        where: "average_income > 800 AND average_income <= 1000",
        polygonOptions: {
            fillColor: '#003466'
        }
    }, {
        where: 'average_income > 100 AND average_income <= 800',
        polygonOptions: {
            fillColor: '#376798'
        }
    }]
});
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/dqthnw7s/3/)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks.

Comment: @Tarqu1n, If this answer addressed your question, please [accept it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)